# Read content of a file off a remote svn repo without checking it out locally

Tags: ruby, svn, bash

(Thanks in advance, SOers!)

**Problem I'm trying to solve**

Is there a way (e.g., in bash or in ruby) to read the content of a file on a remote svn repo without first checking it out locally and read it locally, given I have the path to it (e.g., "svn+ssh://svn.something/folder/morefolder/something.txt")

**Things I've tried or thought of trying**

There isn't a counterpart for something like `more` or `less` as an `svn` option. Looking at the list of available options for the svn command, the closest possible thing I can think of to achieve this is something along the line of

1. Using `svn praise [svn file path]`, and then
2. Parse it accordingly (in my program or in bash) to extract what I want out of it.

**Additional Note**

I've googled and looked around on StackOverflow, and it seems like no one else (or at least I haven't yet come across anyone) has discussed about this problem/usecase.  I have a legit reason for this specific need but I do wonder if I'm missing anything in my thought process.

Please let me know if I'm missing any info in this question.  Thanks again!

Comment: svn cat requires a local checkout? Haven't tried without one.

Comment: svn doesn't require a local checkout, it seems.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried svn cat?  I believe that's precisely the functionality you are seeking.

Here's the documentation
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.cat.html

This command conveniently outputs the contents of the remote repository URL to stdout.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works! 

me-- on this one.  I did remember seeing cat as one of the options when I was reading svn help but I assumed it was for something else before actually reading that particular option.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the repo > Click " browse "
This opens up a web replica of the repo then you can find the file you are interested in and click it to read the content.